# Electron notarization failed due to "The binary uses an SDK older than the 10.9 SDK."

Tags: macos, electron, notarize

I'm trying to get notarization working for my electron app. Apple failed to notarize my App due to "The binary uses an SDK older than the 10.9 SDK". I assume it refers to MacOS SDK. I could not find reference in Electron documentation about how to configure MacOS SDK version being used in the building process. I'm using Xcode 10.1, Electron 4.0.0, Electron-builder 20.44.4. My question comes down to what actually controls the SDK version used by electron? Is it Xcod, Electron version or some setting in my system?

Comment: I just had the same issue, do you happen to be including any third party binaries in your app? I was including a GoLang command line utility as part of my `extraResources`. Removing it allowed the app to pass.

Comment: @Nate Everything works after I updated dependencies and moved some dependencies to dev-dependencies. It's definitely some old third party binaries that caused the problem. Thanks heaps for the comment/answer. However, I still have no idea how this building process actually works.

Comment: I am facing the same issue for a Maven Java app packaged as DMG and is using PDFBox but am not sure what to do ?

Comment: @Todanley, I'm getting the same error. How you were able to find out what 3rd party binaries are causing the issue. Can you please help

Answer (score -1):

Came across this error in 2020. This is going to sound snide, but it may be helpful to others; in our case, the problem was... exactly what the error message reported; we needed to recompile our external dynamic libraries using the 10.9 SDK.

Comment: what do you mean by recompile external libraries. Can you please name the libraries which are defined as external resources in your project