# Electron notarisation failed due to The binary uses an SDK older than the 10.9 SDK

Tags: javascript, macos, electron, electron-builder, electron-notarize

We are trying to notarise the electron app but I'm getting this error.The versions which we are using are
electron: 3.0.6,
electron-builder": "^21.2.0

```
{
"logFormatVersion": 1,
"jobId": "---",
"status": "Invalid",
"statusSummary": "Archive contains critical validation errors",
"statusCode": 4000,
"archiveFilename": "App.zip",
"uploadDate": "2020-10-29T16:19:57Z",
"sha256": "7e3996fbdc7bc2cd9e124720dad235393ffa652119fa466f09b47252d0b500b4",
"ticketContents": null,
"issues": [
 {
  "severity": "error",
  "code": null,
  "path": 
    "App.zip/App.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/app- 
     builder-bin/mac/app-builder",
  "message": "The binary uses an SDK older than the 10.9 SDK.",
  "docUrl": null,
  "architecture": "x86_64"
 }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By installing some dependencies and moving some dependency to dev-dependencies worked for me. In my case, `electron-publisher-s3` I moved this package to dev dependency. This ticket helped me [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57172988/electron-notarization-failed-due-to-the-binary-uses-an-sdk-older-than-the-10-9)